# Amazon EC2: permission denied when attempting to create .crt file

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, permissions

I am trying to set up our EC2 instance with an SSL. Non-SSL web traffic has always been fine.

I'm following the tutorial here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

On step 2 part 5 it says to remove the old certificate from /etc/pki/tls/certs and place the new certificate here.

> Remove the old self-signed host certificate localhost.crt from the /etc/pki/tls/certs directory and place the new CA-signed certificate there (along with any intermediate certificates).

Unfortunately I get permission denied errors when attempting both. I've tried through console SSH and through FileZilla SSH, and as expected, both have the same problem. I'm logged in as ec2-user.

I'm able to create / modify / delete files in other directories, such as the public web folders etc, but this directory seems to have more protection.

Does anyone know how to get the necessary permissions in this directory so I can complete setup?

Comment: Use `sudo` for root access

Comment: ...and don't try to change the permissions of the directory.

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92 that worked perfectly. For anyone else who's unfamiliar with sudo and interested in learning, this was a decent read - https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/linux-commands-for-beginners-sudo/

Comment: Is there a way to `sudo` into the remote over `scp`?  I just scped the file into my home dir then did a `sudo mv`